# Make a list with ng-repeat, separated by "custom categories" (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need a create a list with values that people will enter in a list, and I need to display them separated **by Category,** only problem is that I don't know which Category they will use for each element, so categories are *custom values*. Here's a example of how I want to display the list:

> **Category 1:**
> - Element 1
> - Element 2
> - Element 3
>   **Category 2:**
> - Element 1
> - Element 2
> - Element 3
>   **Category invented by me:**
> - Element 1
> - Element 2

I tried making an **ng-repeat** of the elements with a filter to avoid all the duplicated Categories. Then I show the title of the category and below the title another ng-repeat now to show the elements of that category but with an ng-if to filter only the ones that match  the category of the previous ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in elements | unique:'Category'">
     <h2>{{x.Category}}</h2>
     <div class="element" ng-repeat="y in elements" ng-if="y.Category === {{x.Category}}">
        <p class="click-text">{{y.Title}}</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

I know this is a mess... I need help on searching an actual solution.

---

Here a example of the array of elements:

```
[{
  "Category": "Category 1",
  "Title": "Title example",
  "Comments": "Example comments"
},
{
  "Category": "Category 1",
  "Title": "My cat is named George",
  "Comments": "Example comments"
},
{
  "Category": "Category 1",
  "Title": "Hocus pokus",
  "Comments": "Example comments"
},
{
  "Category": "Category 2",
  "Title": "7 projects going LIVE now",
  "Comments": "Example comments"
},
{
  "Category": "Category 2",
  "Title": "Batman vs Superman was a good movie",
  "Comments": "Example comments"
},
{
  "Category": "Category 2",
  "Title": "projects (more)",
  "Comments": "Example comments"
},
{
  "Category": "Category invented by me",
  "Title": "Remember, remember the fifth of november",
  "Comments": "Hello there!"
},
{
  "Category": "Category invented by me",
  "Title": "It's night, electric night",
  "Comments": "General Kenobi"
}]
```

Comment: Seems like it's better to maintain a mapping from categories to their respective elements in your controller. Can you please share what your elements array currently looks like?

Comment: @slider I added an example array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group elements by category in an object and iterate by object properties. See "Iterating over object properties" in the [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) documentation.

When you add a new element, you can add it to the object too (in the array next to the new element's category).

You can see a working demo below (note how the mapping from categories to corresponding elements is created in the `vm.init` function):

```js
angular
  .module('elementsApp', [])
  .controller('elements', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.elements = [{
        "Category": "Category 1",
        "Title": "Title example",
        "Comments": "Example comments"
      },
      {
        "Category": "Category 1",
        "Title": "My cat is named George",
        "Comments": "Example comments"
      },
      {
        "Category": "Category 1",
        "Title": "Hocus pokus",
        "Comments": "Example comments"
      },
      {
        "Category": "Category 2",
        "Title": "7 projects going LIVE now",
        "Comments": "Example comments"
      },
      {
        "Category": "Category 2",
        "Title": "Batman vs Superman was a good movie",
        "Comments": "Example comments"
      },
      {
        "Category": "Category 2",
        "Title": "projects (more)",
        "Comments": "Example comments"
      },
      {
        "Category": "Category invented by me",
        "Title": "Remember, remember the fifth of november",
        "Comments": "Hello there!"
      },
      {
        "Category": "Category invented by me",
        "Title": "It's night, electric night",
        "Comments": "General Kenobi"
      }
    ];
    vm.newElement = {};
    vm.elementGroups = {};

    vm.addElement = function(e) {
      vm.elements.push(e);
      vm.elementGroups[e.Category] = vm.elementGroups[e.Category] || [];
      vm.elementGroups[e.Category].push(e);
      vm.newElement = {};
    };

    vm.init = function() {
      vm.elements.forEach(e => {
        vm.elementGroups[e.Category] = vm.elementGroups[e.Category] || [];
        vm.elementGroups[e.Category].push(e);
      });
    };


  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="elementsApp">
  <div ng-controller="elements as ctrl" ng-init="ctrl.init()">
    <form ng-submit='ctrl.addElement(ctrl.newElement)'>
      <input ng-model="ctrl.newElement.Title" placeholder='Title' required>
      <input ng-model="ctrl.newElement.Category" placeholder='Category' required>
      <button type='submit'>Add</button>
    </form>

    <div ng-repeat="(category, elements) in ctrl.elementGroups">
      <h2>{{category}}</h2>
      <div ng-repeat="element in elements">
        {{element.Title}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```